# ArrayIndexOutofBound error, I just want to enter elements into 2d String array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Cakeminator{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        int i,j,r=0,c=0;
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    Scanner stdin=new Scanner(System.in);   



    // String[][] a=new String[r][c];
    // entering rows length
    r=stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("rows . "+r);

    //entering columns length
    c=stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cols . "+c);

    String[][] a=new String[r][c];

    //entering elements into matrix 
    for(i=0;i<=r-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=c-1;j++){
           a[i][j]=br.readLine();   
        }
    }
    // printing matrix
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            System.out.println("\t");   
            System.out.println(a[i][j]);    
        }
    }
    }

}
```

// after changing the array declaration place in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from `0` and goes until `n-1`. So change your loop from:

```
for(i=0;i<=r;i++){
```

To

```
for(i=0;i<r;i++) {//go till r-1.
```

Also define

```
String[][] a=new String[r][c];
```

After you have values of `r` and `c` from users i.e. after `System.out.println("cols . "+c);` else it will be initialized with 0 row and 0 column as you initialized r and c with 0.

Answer (score 0):

your code has two flaws one is your definition of 2-D array and second one is loop condition.

define array after taking input dimensions.and put condition to  exiting index.

if length of array is n then max index value will be `n-1`. change your code as below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Cakeminator{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        int i,j,r=0,c=0;
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    Scanner stdin=new Scanner(System.in);   




    // entering rows length
    r=stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("rows . "+r);

    //entering columns length
    c=stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cols . "+c);

    String[][] a=new String[r][c];
    //entering elements into matrix 
    for(i=0;i<=r-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
           a[i][j]=br.readLine();   
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Still for loop is taking more values than required.

Comment: @MediLethesh your condition should not overflow the array index value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your code you are declering String array first and then adding row and column from runtime.
So To resolve this receive row and column first  and then declear String array

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.*;

public class Cakeminator{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        int i,j,r=0,c=0;
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    Scanner stdin=new Scanner(System.in);   

    // entering rows length
    r=stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("rows . "+r);

    //entering columns length
    c=stdin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("cols . "+c);

    String[][] a=new String[r][c];
    //entering elements into matrix 
    for(i=0;i<=r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
           a[i][j]=br.readLine();   
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,you should change one places.First you should put `String[][] a = new String[r][c]` after the line `System.out.println("cols . "+c)`.